# Inputting Data into UI element using Locust

Tags: python, testing, https, load-testing, locust

so i'm pretty new to locust and load testing, but i need to insert specific values into different fields on my website.  Trying to load test adding multiple items to an order using 50ish users.  Hopefully each user having a different order in the end.  Right now i have been able to log into my site and navigate between tabs, but thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Locust acts on [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) protocol level, it doesn't "input" anything into "UI elements", it sends associated [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), most probably it will be [HTTP Post request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) containing field name and the value.

So basically it will be pretty much similar to the "login" but with different field names and values, you can capture the requests using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and then re-create them using Locust API or alternatively you can try [Locust.Replay](https://github.com/zlorb/locust.replay#locustreplay) project which implements record and replay capability for Locust and it will generate some code for you.

More information: [How to Run Locust with Different Users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-locust-with-different-users)